# migration to Tomcat9, Java17, Jersey, Weld

Tags: jersey, tomcat9, java-17, jboss-weld

I have an existing Java REST service I'm trying to upgrade from Tomcat8, Java8, Jersey(2.23), and Weld(2.4.8). I'm using Weld for CDI so that my service classes get instantiated and injected where they're needed in the resource classes. Everything works fine. I have this project defined as a Gradle7 project currently.

Moving to Java17 seems to have required no changes.
Moving to Tomcat9 only required me to change from `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.+` to `jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:4.+`.
I'm getting stuck/confused on Jersey and Weld/CDI.

I'm also confused about `javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.+` vs `jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:3.+`. I'm pretty sure this is related to Jersey though and only requires me to switch my imports from `javax` to `jakarta`.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated since I feel like I'm just spinning at this point.

Answer (score 0):

As Java EE / Jakarta EE evolved, the version of APIs evolved too. At some point the maven artifact names changed from `javax` to `jakarta`, and later the java package names moved from `java` to `jakarta`. And there were two versions of 8.

```
| EE Version  | java package names | artifact names | Servlet | JAX-RS |
|-------------|--------------------|----------------|---------|--------|
| Java EE 7   |    javax           | javax          | 3.1     |  2.0   |
| Java EE 8   |    javax           | javax          | 4.0     |  2.1   |
| Jakarta EE 8|    javax           | jakarta        | 4.0.4   |  2.1.6 |
| Jakarta EE 9|    jakarta         | jakarta        | 5.0     |  3.0   |
|Jakarta EE 10|    jakarta         | jakarta        | 6.0     |  3.1   |
```

See the Tomcat [version matrix](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html). There you can find versions of the servlet supported. From that, one can derive the Jersey, CDI, and Weld versions required. The table might look as follows:

```
| Tomcat | Servlet | javax vs. jakarta | Jersey | JAX-RS | CDI | Weld |
|:------:|:-------:|:-----------------:|:------:|:------:|:---:|:----:|  
|  8.x   |  3.1    | javax             | 2.25.1 |   2.0  | 2.0 | 3.0  |
|  9.x   |  4.0    | javax/jakarta     | 2.26+  |   2.1  |2.0.2| 3.x  |
| 10.0.x |  5.0    | jakarta           | 3.0.x  |   3.0  | 3.0 | 4.x  |
| 10.1.x |  6.0    | jakarta           | 3.1.x  |   3.1  | 4.0 | 5.x  |
```

Jersey started to [support JDK 17](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/wiki/Road-Map) partially since 2.34, better in 2.35.

So you need:

```
| Tomcat | Servlet                   | JAX-RS                  | Jersey|
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  9.x   | jakarta.servlet-api:4.0.4 | jakarta.ws.rs-api:2.1.6 | 2.35+ |
|  10.0.x| jakarta.servlet-api:5     | jakarta.ws.rs-api:3.0   | 3.0.x |
|  10.1.x| jakarta.servlet-api:6     | jakarta.ws.rs-api:3.1   | 3.1.x |
```

Please do not use Jersey 2.35, better start with the fixed latest version.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I ended up moving to Tomcat10.1 and this made things easier. I am curious to know how you knew to pick jakarta.ws.rs-api:2.1.6 though. More specifically, how did you "derive the Jersey, CDI, and Weld versions" based on the version matrix?

Comment: `jakarta.ws.rs-api:2.1.6` is the final Jakarta EE 8 version, and the changes to any 2.1 are minor (licensing, javadoc updates, etc.); any 2.1 would technically do, but may be insufficient for instance legal-wise. I summed up the dependencies as they are hard to find - mostly obtained the hard way, as the dependency of each implementation, spec, and API, from maven poms.